# I implemented card views in XML on Android Studios. How can I have this act as buttons?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-cardview

I'm new to Android and recently created a dashboard for my app. I followed a tutorial but it only covered the front end. I created a layout called **content_main.xml** with three Cardviews. Each of these Cardviews contains the code

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Beginning the back end of things, I created a java receiver class called **DashboardActivity** (as seen below). I want to make my Cardviews clickable so that when one is clicked, I am taken to another screen within my app. The other screens in my app I am trying to get to are fragments. Each of these screens has its own java class in my "Fragments" folder. One of them, of which I try calling on in the code that follows is called **SettingsViewFragment()**.

So far, I have tried the following. It does nothing.

```
public class DashboardActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

    CardView cd1, cd2, cd3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        cd1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.dash_settings);
        cd2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.dash_profile);
        cd3 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.dash_activity);

        cd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment1 = new SettingsViewFragment();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE: FULL CODE

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CardView cd1, cd2, cd3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        cd1 = findViewById(R.id.dash_settings);
        cd2 = findViewById(R.id.dash_profile);
        cd3 = findViewById(R.id.dash_activity);

        cd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("Testing 123 123 123");
            }

        });

    }
}
```

And my XML: (it continues for 3 cards this way)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.newproject.DashboardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/toolbar">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/dash_settings"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_circle1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_settingspicture"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="View your settings"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Follow along with guided tutorials"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Fragment fragment1 = new SettingsViewFragment();
```

With this

```
Fragment fragment1 = new SettingsViewFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Main_Layout,fragment1);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: This compiles and makes more sense to me, but still nothing is happening. I can't get onClick to work whatsoever. Do you think I need to move this code in my receiver class to an adapter class instead?

Comment: You can move it anywhere and i personally handle all the on item click listener of recyclerview on adapter. But it should work here also. Try with printing log inside onClick

Comment: I might try that. It's not working in the receiver class at all.. I tried testing with log output and nothing happened!

Comment: Show your complete code then it will help us to figure out what exactly problem is

Comment: okay I have edited my question to include my full code now. Onclick is still not working at all

Comment: Where you filling data in cardview and where is adapter

Comment: I don't have any sort of adapter. All I have is this XML class (content_main.xml) as a layout and my activity class (DashboardActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

Change `Fragment fragment1 = new SettingsViewFragment ();` by `Toast.makeText (mActivity, "onCLick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show ();`

//if show toast The problem is not the onClick, the problem is when loading the fragment

Comment: Ok. The problem is onClick, not the fragments. I think I need to make an Adapter class and delete this Receiver class I'm currently working in. That's what I keep reading...

Answer (score 0):

Fragments should be instantiated with the `newInstance()` static method.

```
cd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment settingsFragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentView, settingsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

});
```

In the SettingsFragment

```
 public static SettingsFragment newInstance() {
            return new SettingsFragment();
 }
```

XML for content_main

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/dash_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        ...

     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/dash_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        ...

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/dash_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        ...

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will transact the fragment into the FrameLayout that is positioned below the CardViews. Now this is probably not ideal, you would most likely want to launch a new activity that will host the fragment but this should work. Unless this is already in some Activity that hosts the fragment. But the key code is in the `onClick`.

Comment: "Fragments should be instantiated with the newInstance() static method." Not true. You can do it for your own convenience. But it's not a  rule

Comment: While technically true, it is good practice, and a Google recommended practice due to how Fragment constructors are used by the System. This is also the only way to reliably pass data to a Fragment. See this stack post explaining it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Comment: Read the post and I agree with you now. Gonna rewrite all nonstatic instantiations tomorrow:)